# Excel array formula to do an hlookup for the first match exceeding a target cell

Tags: excel, vlookup, array-formulas

I am not sure how to phrase this other than showing an example and describing what I think is an aproach:

[image: Example]

I need to find the minimum value of from row #2 where the record for A, B, or C exceeds the cutoff value in `B1`. Basically the first "green" cell. I feel like this is some type of `HLOOKUP` or `INDEX(MATCH())`, but array formulas are no longer my strong suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($2:$2,MATCH($B$1,INDEX($3:$5,MATCH(B8,$B$3:$B$5,0),0))+1)
```

Comment: As always, awesome formula. Can you help me understand the `0` column argument on the inner `INDEX()`? Specifically, the last zero from this part: `INDEX($3:$5,MATCH(B8,$B$3:$B$5,0),0)`

Comment: It returns the whole row.

Comment: Interesting, yet you don't need an array formula to use that row array "later"?